# Joomla sef404 301 redirection problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting, redirect

I have my site in `joomla` having `sef404 rewriting` component install in it. It is having a really good page ranking in Google.But the problem is that i want to do `301 redirection` of some of my article to my new site.

I am trying something like below but it is not working:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^somearticle(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/somearticle [R=301,L]
```

I know sef404 is conflicting somewhere but what is the solution than?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you tried to put the original URL instead of the "translated" one?

Comment: not exactly i think u mean by index.php?cat=3..something right ?

Comment: 1) Show your current .htaccess from the root folder (update your question) 2) Do you have any other .htaccess files? 3) The rule you have tried so far -- where did you put it -- in .htaccess or server config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write something like this in your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 somearticle.html http://domain.com/somearticle.html
```

Comment: What exactly are you writing? Maybe you making mistakes in regular expressions(if you are using them)? Try write whole URL of source and destination articles. It should work. I'm using the same method of redirection on my sites.